# Using multiple form submit buttons with an if/elif statement

Tags: python, django, forms, if-statement

I am using a python form which takes the values of two submit buttons and performs the next task based on which was selected.

Here's a snippet:

**Template**

```
<div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" value="Submit">
            Submit
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom" name="addanother" id="addanother">
            Submit &amp; Add Another
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="history.go(-1);return false;">
            Cancel
        </button>
    </div>
</div><!-- Panel Footer -->
```

**View**

```
if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            #do function

        if 'submit' in request.POST:

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("userdetail", args=(new_user.id,)))

        elif 'addanother' in request.POST:

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("adduser",))
```

The problem I have is that this form does not redirect when the 'addanother' button is clicked. (*The form still submits though.*)

**Quick Fix**

I have managed to do quick fix this issue by replacing:

```
elif 'addanother' in request.POST:
```

with:

```
else:
```

But this is still an issue as I plan on using more than two submit buttons in the forms following on from this one.

Has anyone came across this before and know what the issue is?

Thanks in advance

Comment: All I can suggest is try reformatting it? Maybe don't have spaces between the statement and the return, you maybe confusing the compiler

Comment: Thanks @SmallLegend for your suggestion, I've just tried it, unfortunately no change.

Comment: Maybe assign the request.POST to a variable and then check the variable in the if the statements rather than continuously calling request.POST, this way you can print out the value and check that 'addanother' is actually be parsed, it could also maybe a problem with using singular parentheses rather than double

Comment: Does it work if you add a `value` attribute to the addanother button, like you do with the submit one?

Comment: You have `value="Submit"` but then you check for `if 'submit' in request.POST`. Will the case of `S / s` not have an effect? In which case I'm not sure what it is matching.

Comment: It should be matching the key in the `request.POST` dictionary, which is from the `name` attribute.

Comment: Have you check how request.POST looks like when your view gets it? Simple `print request.POST` before if statement should show you what's going on and what statement use.

Comment: @MateuszKnapczyk I've just printed the request.POST and it shows that the correct button is being pressed - but still not redirecting

Comment: @DanielRoseman - Tried adding a value but this has no affect

Comment: You do realise that when this form is submitted both addanother and submit will be sent along with request. So even if you add few more buttons in same fashion the sanity of code will be screwed. Perhaps you can make use of javascript to submit forms, and there can decide what you want to do. I mean simple submit or redirect. It will be helpful when you add more buttons.